# Selector on property of data associated with a element

Tags: cytoscape.js

I'm trying to use a selector to filter nodes in cytoscape.js depending on data associated with the nodes.

I seems like it is not possible to filter data that is "sub"-property of a property added as data to a node.

```
cy.nodes("[type = 'typeA']")          - works
cy.nodes("[metadata.type = 'typeA']") - fails
```

I have tried escaping the "\\." but haven't been able to get it to work.

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": "run-jmh",
    "metadata": {
      "type": "typeA",
    }
    "type": "typeA",
  },
  "position": {
    "x": 550,
    "y": 23
  },
  "group": "nodes",
  "removed": false,
  "selected": false,
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selectors strings don't support arbitrary JS syntax, so things like `foo.bar` or `foo['bar']` aren't going to work.  The selectors are really just for simple top-level data fields, similar to how you'd use selectors on attributes in HTML.

If you need more complex, arbitrary logic you can use a function for style property values, e.g.:

```
cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById('cy'),

  // ...

  style: cytoscape.stylesheet()
    .selector('node')
      .style({
        'background-color': function( ele ){ return ele.data('bg') }

        // which works the same as

        // 'background-color': 'data(bg)'
      })

      // ...


  // , ...
});
```

Ref : http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/format

In this case, you'd classify your elements as matching or not etc. in the function along with a general selector like `node`.